# Array compare if value exist add value otherwise 0 in indexes

Tags: php

[After 1st answer my output is one value missing my ratting lenght is According to Array2 not Array !,,,,,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0USsT.png)Input:

I want this output:
[image: I want this type output]
My output is getting 0,0,0,0

I want to compare two arrays with different length, if matches the add the value, if not then add "0" and skip after assign and go to first loop

My code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($custt1);$i++){

    for($j=0;$j<count($items);$j++){

        if($items[$j]==$custt1[$i]){
            $x[$j]=$rating[$j]; 
        }
        else{   
            $x[$j]=0;
        }
    }

    for($j=0;$j<count($items1);$j++){

        if($items1[$j]==$custt1[$i]){
            $y[$j]=$rating1[$j];
        }
        else{
            $y[$j]=0;
        }
    }   
}
```

I want to save in x and y array if value present then add rating otherwise "0" and go to first loop but I am facing in index 0 if value not present add 0 and on 8 indexes. Hope you understand my explanation and please help me to solve this.

```
now  my output is by applying 1st answer
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 5 in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Rest\new2.php</b> on line
<b>79</b>
<br />

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
)
```

Because i am implementing recommendation system

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "hfc";
    $array;
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($connection) {
$sql1="SELECT item_name
from feedback

GROUP BY item_name";

$sql="SELECT customer_email_address AS customeremail,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
           DISTINCT CONCAT(cook_email_address,'-',item_name,'-',rating)
        ) AS uniqueItem
   FROM feedback
GROUP BY customer_email_address";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {

  $customer_email[] = $row['customeremail'];
    $cust1[]= $row['uniqueItem'].",";
  }



$item[] = explode(",",$cust1[0]);



for($i=0;$i<count($item[0])-1;$i++){
$item_rating[] = explode("-",$item[0][$i]);
}
  print_r ($item_rating);
for($i=0;$i<count($item_rating);$i++){

        $items[]=$item_rating[$i][1];
        $rating[]=$item_rating[$i][2];


}



$item1[] = explode(",",$cust1[1]);


for($i=0;$i<count($item1[0])-1;$i++){
$item_rating1[] = explode("-",$item1[0][$i]);
}
  print_r ($item_rating1);
for($i=0;$i<count($item_rating1);$i++){

        $items1[]=$item_rating1[$i][1];
        $rating1[]=$item_rating1[$i][2];


}



$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
    $custt1[]= $row['item_name'];

  }
  print_r ($custt1);
 print_r ($items);
 $output = array();
foreach ($custt1 as  $i =>$item) {

    if (in_array($item, $items)) {
        $output[] = $rating[$i];


    } else {
        $output[] = 0;

    }




}

 print_r ($output);
for($i=0;$i<count($custt1);$i++){

    for($j=0;$j<count($items);$j++){



        if($items[$j]==$custt1[$i]){


        $x[$i]=$rating[$j];

        }
        else{

            $x[$i]=0;



        }


    }


    for($j=0;$j<count($items1);$j++){

        if($items1[$j]==$custt1[$i]){
            $y[$j]=$rating1[$j];

        }

        else{

            $y[$j]=0;

        }
    }


}





 print_r ($x);
 print_r ($y);





  for($i1=0;$i1<count($custt1);$i1++)
  {

     $array[]=explode(",",$custt1[$i1]);  
  }
  // echo count($array);
 // print_r($custt1)."<br>";


  /*for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
  {
     for($y=1;$y<count($array);$y++)
     {
         $pearson=Corr($array[$i],$array[$y],$c=count($array));
     }

  }*/
  $pearson=Corr($array);

   echo $pearson;
}

function Corr(&$arr){
    $x=$arr[0];
    $y=$arr[1];
$length=count($x)-1;

$mean1=array_sum($x)/ $length;
$mean2=array_sum($y)/ $length;

echo $mean1."mean of x";
echo $mean2."mean of y";
echo "\n";
//echo $mean2;

$a=0;
$b=0;
$axb=0;
$a2=0;
$b2=0;

for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
{
$a=$x[$i]-$mean1;
$b=$y[$i]-$mean2;
$axb=$axb+($a*$b);
$a2=$a2+ pow($a,2);
$b2=$b2+ pow($b,2);
$corr= $axb / sqrt($a2*$b2);


}   

return $corr;
}

?>
```

Comment: show the input and the expected output

Comment: Check top of the quetion i added a snapshot click on "i want this type output" Thanks @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, try adding the expected output in a code snippet.  It makes the question a bit cleaner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in_array()` to tell if the element of array 1 is in array 2.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array1 as $i => $item) {
    if (in_array($item, $array2)) {
        $output[] = $rating[$i];
    } else {
        $output[] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: i also want to fetch rating against every item and show rating instead of item but compare with item  ....

Comment: Where is that in the screenshot?

Comment: sorry i change but by mistake i added old one sorry

Comment: answer if you there?

Comment: I don't understand. Where does 33 come from?

Comment: if item match  $rating [$i] show otherwise 0, you answer is right but i need ratting if item match and show rating

Comment: Why isn't the `$rating` array in the screen shot?

Comment: check after changes code output on the top of question i attach new output snapshot

Comment: I'm done with this. If you're a competent programmer, you should be able to adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: Please post plain text, not images.

Comment: I guess there's no `$rating[5]`. What is it supposed to use if there's no rating for the item?

Comment: Array1 is lentgh 8 and $item length is 5 and ratting also same if item matches to array1 then put its ratting otherwise 0

Comment: So is the index in `$rating` the same as the index in `$item`, not the index in array 1? Why do you have two different arrays, why don't you use an associative array `$rating = array ('aloo' => 13, 'tomato' => 33)`?